# Cron expression to run only on Monday

Tags: spring-boot, cron, quartz-scheduler, quartz, crontrigger

I am using [quartz expressions](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.2.x/tutorials/crontrigger.html) to create a trigger that should execute only on Mondays and the `day of month` should not be `1`.

I already know that `0 5 0 2-31 * MON` expression doesn't work because `Specifying both a day-of-week and a day-of-month parameter is not implemented`. Is there any workaround for this issue? How can I achieve this?

To summarize, if 1st day of month is Monday, the above expression should not be executed but for other Mondays of the month, it should be executed.

Answer (score 2):

As **support for specifying both a day-of-week AND a day-of-month parameter is not implemented,** You can try with this:

```
@Scheduled(cron = "0 5 0 ? * MON")
private void doTask(){
    if(LocalDate.now().getDayOfMonth() != 1){
        //your code here
    }
}
```

You can also **check** and **generate** corn for quartz [*here*](https://www.freeformatter.com/cron-expression-generator-quartz.html).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I actually thought of this, but I wanted quartz expression to do this.